# Atm machine logic error at array input

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have created an application about ATM machine that have an array account size of 10 but for some weird reason, the input only accept 0(first id), but not the other 9 ids for the other ids, it always show the Invalid id error message. I've stuck for hours searching for the error.

the ones that related to checking the ids would be these two;

```
public static boolean hasID(Account acc[], int id){ //this is to check whether the id exist or not.
    for(int i=0; i<acc.length; i++){
        if(id == acc[i].getID()){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static int gID(Account[] acc){  //this is the login method to initiate the hasID method.
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int id=0;
    boolean valid = false;
    while(!valid){
        System.out.println("Enter ID: ");
        id = sc.nextInt();

        if(!hasID(acc, id)){
            System.out.println("YOUR ID IS INVALID.");
        } else{
            valid = true;
        }
    }
    return id;
}

public Account(int mID, double mBalance/*, double mInterestRate*/){
    this.id = getID();
    this.balance = getBalance();
    //this.interestRate = getInterestRate();
}

public static Account getAccount(Account acc[], int id){
    for(int i = 0; i<acc.length; i++){
        if(id == acc[i].getID()){
            return acc[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and here is my main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Account acc[] = new Account[10];
    for(int i = 0; i<acc.length; i++){
        acc[i] = new Account(i, 100.0);
    }

    int a = 0;
    int id = gID(acc);

    while(a != 4){
        Account ac = getAccount(acc,id);
        System.out.println("1: Check Balance");
        System.out.println("2: Withdraw");
        System.out.println("3: Deposit");
        System.out.println("4: Exit");

        System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");
        a = sc.nextInt();
        switch(a){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Your Balance is: RM " + ac.getBalance());
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("Amount to withdraw: RM ");
            ac.withdraw(sc.nextDouble());
            break;

        case 3:
            System.out.println("Amount to deposit: RM ");
            ac.deposit(sc.nextDouble());
            break;

        case 4:
            id = gID(acc);
            a = 0;
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid input!");
        }
    }

}
```

Edit: Account constructor, the insterestrate is not used.
The setter and getter for id and balance:

```
public int getID(){
    return id;
}

public void setID(int mID){
    id = mID;
}

public double getBalance(){
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(double mBalance){
    balance = mBalance;
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your `Account` constructor and `Account#getID` method code (at a minimum) would be needed for us to help you.

Comment: @AJNeufeld edited, forgot to put it

Comment: Examine `this.id = getID();` please. I believe you want `this.id = mID;`.  Otherwise, `getID()` is just going to return the uninitialized value of id ... which would be zero.

Comment: @AJNeufeld wow that's the cause! thanks! I have another question I wonder how can I use the getter and setter.

Comment: You could use the setters in your constructor, instead of directly setting the fields, like this:  `{ setID(mID); setBalance(mBalance); }`.   But there is no reason to do so.  And the public setters for ID and Balance are dangerous: the Account ID should be initialized by the constructor and should never, ever change.  “I’d like to check my balance: Account #123” “sorry, that Account # doesn’t exist anymore.  Someone must have changed the account number.”   Setting the balance is equally suspicious: the balance should change only through deposits and withdrawals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Account(int mID, double mBalance/*, double mInterestRate*/){
    this.id = getID();
    this.balance = getBalance();
    //this.interestRate = getInterestRate();
}
```

Shouldn't you be using

```
 public Account(int mID, double mBalance/*, double mInterestRate*/){
    this.id = mID;
    this.balance = mBalance;
    //this.interestRate = getInterestRate();
 }
```

getters and  setter are part of the FIELDS ENCAPSULATION, but for better user experiance I could suggest you the following code

```
public Account(/*you dont need a parameter*/){
   this.id = setIdByScannedValue();
   this.balance = setBalanceByScannedValue();
   //this.interestRate = setInterestRateByScannedValue();
}

private void setIdByScannedValue(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean provided = false;
    while(!provided)
    try{
        System.out.print("provide id: ");
        this.id = sc.nextInt();
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println("you must provide an integer id format !!!");
    }finally{
        provided = true;
    }
}
```

I ll let you do the other methods so you can learn using this idea by your self this way I'll be sure that you understand my code.

Comment: and for getID() it mean to be used in order to get the value of the id in the current object instance, that's what we call an accessor ( it access my variable ) Where the setID is a mutator ( it mutate the id value :: change it or set it)  so set used to write value, get used to read.